# Implementation of the decorator class in C++ using a member reference to the decorated object not working as expected

Tags: c++, oop, c++11, design-patterns, decorator

I am trying to learn the decorator pattern implementation in C++. I have tried implementing the decorator class using both a reference and pointer to the decorated object as a member (composition). A single invocation of decorator works expectedly. However, when I try chaining together multiple decorator instances, it works only when I use the pointer to the decorated object as a decorator class member. For the implementation with the decorated object reference, it fails unexpectedly (please see the output below). I am using GCC with C++11 enabled. Here's the code. The class RedRose is a decorator using the pointer to the base interface while class BlueRose uses the reference to the base interface. I am sorry if I am making a naive mistake but what am I missing?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

class Flower
{
public:
    Flower() {}
    virtual string str() = 0;
};

class Rose : public Flower
{
public:
    Rose() {}
    
    string str() override {
        return "A rose";
    }
};

class RedRose : public Rose
{
private:
  Flower *rose;

public:
  explicit RedRose(Flower *rose) : rose{rose} {}
  
  string str() override
  {
      ostringstream oss;
      oss << rose->str() << " that is red ";
      return oss.str();
  } 
};

class BlueRose : public Rose
{
private:
  Flower &rose;

public:
  explicit BlueRose(Flower &rose) : rose{rose} {}
  
  string str() override
  {
      ostringstream oss;
      oss << rose.str() << " that is blue";
      return oss.str();
  } 
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    
    Rose rose; // The decorated object
    
    // Chaining together docorator with pointer implementation
    RedRose red_rose{&rose};
    RedRose red_red_rose{&red_rose};
    RedRose red_red_red_rose{&red_red_rose};
    
    cout << red_rose.str() << endl;
    cout << red_red_rose.str() << endl;
    cout << red_red_red_rose.str() << endl;
    
    Rose rose2;
    
    // Chaining together docorator with reference implementation
    BlueRose blue_rose{rose2};
    BlueRose blue_blue_rose{blue_rose};
    BlueRose blue_blue_blue_rose{blue_blue_rose};
    
    cout << blue_rose.str() << endl;
    cout << blue_blue_rose.str() << endl;
    cout << blue_blue_blue_rose.str() << endl;
    
    getchar();
}
```

Here's the output

```
A rose that is red 
A rose that is red  that is red 
A rose that is red  that is red  that is red 

A rose that is blue
A rose that is blue
A rose that is blue`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You see the problem if you delete the copy constructors:

```
class Flower
{
public:
    Flower() {}
    Flower(const Flower&) = delete;
    virtual string str() = 0;
};
```

```
error: use of deleted function ‘BlueRose::BlueRose(const BlueRose&)’
     BlueRose blue_blue_rose{blue_rose};
```

`BlueRose` has a constructor taking `Flower&` and another one taking `const BlueRose&`, so the copy constructor is preferred.

One solution would be to generatlize the constructor:

```
  template<typename T>
  explicit BlueRose(T &rose) : rose{rose} {}
```

But really, you shouldn't be using references because they can dangle if the wrapped object lifetime is shorter than the decorator. Try `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your great explanation. So the implicitly declared copy constructor was just overwriting the new object with the existing one (instead of building up the decorator chain)? It is sad that none of the material I was studying considered this detail about implictly declared copy constructor. Sure, I will try the unique_ptr approach now.

Comment: @YasirKhan Not overwriting. Just that instead of calling your constructor that copies the passed reference to the member, it's instead taking the passed in object and copying the passed in object reference instead.